# How can I shorten page references from specific to a range (eg. pg 1-3,6-7,9 to pg 1-9)

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of page references that need to be converted from specific references to min-max references. How can I accomplish this?

Examples and desired results:

```
Current         Desired Result
pg 1-3,6-7,9    pg 1-9
pg 6,7          pg 6-7
pg 1-3          pg 1-3
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen with something like *pg 1-3,5,9* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
(pg\s+)(\d+).*(\d+)
```

And replace with:

```
$1$2-$3
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hZ8tH4/2)